# MYSQL - How to make a table with a column that will sum columns from parent tables?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table called `FOODS`. `FOODS` has two foreign keys: `IDsize` and `IDflavor`.

The parent tables `FLAVOR` and `SIZE` each have a column `price`.

The table `FLAVOR` has columns `IDflavor`, `flavor` and `price` with an example row (1, 'Beef', 10). The table `SIZE` has columns `IDsize`, `size` and `price` with an example row (3, 'BIG', 15).

Is it possible to make a column in `FOODS` that will automatically sum the values of the `price` columns of the corresponding rows in the parent tables `FLAVOR` and `SIZE` (using the foreign keys)? So if `FOODS` has `IDsize = 3` and `IDflavor = 1`, the column should automatically get 25 (10+15).

Comment: I tried to format/clarify your question until I lost track. I suggest to accept my edit suggestion, and make it ready in this style. The main problem is that it is not easy to decode, where your sentences start or end.

Comment: Can you please post table definitions as DDL, and data as DML (insert statements), along with desired output? What query have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking to do is a type of [denormalisation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/understanding-denormalization/): You're adding redundant data to a single table in order to avoid having to query multiple tables to get the same information. This is done to increase performance of `SELECT` queries and/or simplify such queries.

Since the `price` columns are in different tables / rows, you unfortunately can't use [generated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html).

So you're going to have to consider other options:

1. You could use a [`VIEW`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html) on top of the `FOODS` table which summed the `price`s from the two parent tables. So whenever you wanted to `SELECT` from the `FOODS` table (and you wanted to include `sum_price`), you instead `SELECT`ed from this `VIEW`. Something like:

   `CREATE VIEW V_FOODS([the columns of FOODS], sum_price) AS 
     SELECT [the columns of FOODS], FLAVOR.price + SIZE.price AS "sum_price"
     FROM FOODS
       INNER JOIN FLAVOR USING(IDflavor)
       INNER JOIN SIZE USING (IDsize);`

   (As pointed out by RDFozz, note that this isn't actually denormalisation of the data, since the actual data stay in the parent tables.)
2. You could use [`TRIGGER`s](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html) to populate a `sum_price` column in `FOODS`. You would need a trigger on `UPDATE`s to each of `FLAVOR` and `SIZE`, and a trigger on `INSERT`s to `FOODS`.
3. You could have a `sum_price` column in `FOODS` and give your application the responsibility of keeping it up-to-date.
4. You could also give up and not denormalise. Just let your application join `FOODS`, `FLAVOR` and `SIZE` whenever you need the sum of prices.

Comment: Note: I don't believe that a view would actually be considered denormalizing the data, as the actual data is not stored in multiple locations, and doesn't need to be updated in multiple locations. Options 2 and 3 *are* examples of denormalization.

Comment: Thanks @RDFozz - I agree and have updated the answer correspondingly.